# How to calculate my carbon footprints using php

Tags: php

Hello am working on my school project, this project entails me to calculate my bus distance covered, gas consumption and electricity consumption with regards to carbon footprints.

i got a website were it was implemented and convereted it from javascript to php.

http://web.uvic.ca/~bobbyc/

it works just like the link above works, but my issue is how do i knw the formula used is correct.

this is what i did

for kilometeres

```
if ($units == "Kilometres")
{
 if ($distance < 32.2)
 {
   $lbCO2 = 0.41;

   $calculation = $distance * $lbCO2 * 2.7  / 1000;
   echo round ($calculation, 3);
   echo 'metric tons'; 
 }

 else
 {
  $lbCO2 = 0.11;
  $calculation = $distance * $lbCO2 * 2.7  / 1000;
  echo round ($calculation, 3);
  echo 'metric tons';
  }
}
```

for miles

```
// measuring miles
if ($units == "Miles")
{
  if ($distance < 20)
  {
   $lbCO2 = 0.66;

   $calculation = $distance * $lbCO2 * 2.7  / 1000;
   echo round ($calculation, 3);
   echo 'metric tons';
 }
 else
 {
  $lbCO2 = 0.18;
  $calculation = $distance * $lbCO2 * 2.7  / 1000;
  echo round ($calculation, 3);
  echo 'metric tons';
  }
}
```

please i need help on what right formulas to use when converting for the various scenarios as above, e.g bus distance, gas consumption and electricity consumption

thanks

Comment: You do realise that the `carbon` tag here on SO is about the `carbon` library for working with Dates/Times, not with carbon footprints?

Comment: omg God so what can i do, i wasnt allowd to put in carbon footprints tag

Comment: If you want to know whether the formula is right; check the formulae from somewhere like [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_footprint)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't relate to software development.

Comment: yea right, hmmmmmmmm